# Problems with passing model to view from local storage

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

During the initialize function of my app I would like to default to my search page and pass my LeagueCollection as the model.

I am encountering an issue where I can add a watch to this.searchResults in my App initialize and see models: Array[3] as expected,
 but when the this.model.toJSON() in the view is called I get the error object has no method toJSON.

This code was working fine with a in memory collection and then I switched to using backbone.localstorage.js to store the app data locally.

So my question is: why is the model not populated in the view?

In my main.js I have

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "list",
    ...
    },
    initialize: function () {

        this.searchResults = new LeagueCollection();
        this.searchPage = new SearchPage({
            model: this.searchResults.fetch()
        });
        this.searchPage.render();

    },
    ...
});
```

In my Search Page view

```
window.SearchPage = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function () {
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('search-page'));
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        var self = this;

        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.listView = new LeagueListView({el: $('ul', this.el), model: this.model});
        this.listView.render();

        return this;
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Do you want a collection or a model inside `SearchPage`, if you want a collection you should call it `collection` rather than `model`.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect terminology - I mean model

Comment: But you should call it `collection` if it is a collection, otherwise you'll just confuse everyone. View constructors treat the `collection` property specially just like the `model` parameter: http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor

Comment: Yeah, had a look at your link - so collection is part of this.options as well as model, I can see why this is confusing. Thanks! I'll change the question slightly.

Comment: If it is a collection then call use `{collection: c}` in the constructor call and refer to it as `this.collection` inside the view, less confusing that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`collection.fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) doesn't return the collection -- it's asynchronous.  What you probably want is to use its `success` callback:

```
this.searchResults = new LeagueCollection();

var self = this;
this.searchResults.fetch({ 
    success: function(collection, response) {
        self.searchPage = new SearchPage( { model: collection } );
        self.searchPage.render();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! I'll go have a look at the documentation.